# How to get financial year for last two year in C# based on current date

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to get financial year for last two year in C# based on current date.

For example

2018-2019
2019-2020

Comment: How do you define financial year?

Comment: On a standard fiscal calendar, I would think any date in the year 2018 would be the 2018-2019 range, and any date with the year 2019 would be the 2019-2020 range?

Comment: @TimothyG. In the UK the financial year is from April 6th -> April 5th the following year. I imagine other countries have similarly odd arrangements. It's a valid question.

Comment: @Llama I suppose what I mean by standard fiscal calendar is one that simply follows a regular calendar year - January 1 to December 31.  But all the more reason why this question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
Console.WriteLine($"{currentYear - 3}-{currentYear - 2} {currentYear - 2}-{currentYear - 1}");
```